# useState doesn't work when I use it with other function in onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I created this state:

```
const [list, insert] = React.useState(["a","b"]);
```

And I have a button that when I press it, I want it set `list` as `["a","b","c"]`

It works:

```
<button onClick={() => insert(list.concat(["c"]))}>Insert</button>
```

But it doesn't:

```
<button onClick={() => {list.push("c");insert(list)}}>Insert</button>
```

And I don't know why

Comment: push mutates original array, while concat don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterward may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

use spread operation :

```
this.setState({ myArray: [...this.state.myArray, 'new value'] }) //simple value
this.setState({ myArray: [...this.state.myArray, ...[1,2,3] ] }) //another array
```

in your case :

```
insert([...list,'c'])
```